# How can I pick color from any website I visit using Chrome DevTools?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, color-picker

When I visit websites I want to save interesting colors I found on them.

*How can I use **Chrome DevTools** to pick color code from the page I am currently seeing?*

NB: *I dont want to use third party plugins* like chrome extension plugins.

Comment: You can inspect the element which contains the colour you're interested in and look at the `CSS`.

Comment: k, thanks but what if the element is an image?

Comment: If it is an image, you can't check the colour with chrome. You'll need a third-party app.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### You can pick color from any element using google chrome

**1.** **Picking color from HTML element**:
If the color is on simple html elements like `button`, `text`, `span` etc you can inspect the element and copy its color, as mentioned on the comment.

[image]

**2.** **Picking color from image**:
If the color is on an image or background image, or background-color of nested html elements, you can use the ff strategy.

*2.1.* Start by inspecting simple element anywhere from the page that could show the color picker box.

[image]

*2.2.*  Then after clicking the above color picker box, goto the image or background image you want to pick color from(*when you do this you will notice the cursor changing from pointer to chrome-color-picker icon*).

[image: color-pick-from-image]

As matter of fact **you can use solution 2 even for case 1**.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the eyedropper tool now in DevTools too http://paul.kinlan.me/eyedropper-chrome-dev-tools/

Answer (score 1):

Use experimental feature in Chrome called **CSS Overview**. No Chrome extension or external tool is required to get overview of colors used on any website

To activate CSS Overview

1. Open up **DevTools**
2. Go to **DevTool Settings** (cog icon or use the F1 key)
3. Open **Experiments** section
4. Enable **CSS Overview** option

[image]

This will make the **CSS Overview** tab available in DevTools

You can click any color to list relevant elements

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use chrome extensions. I have tried two of them and they are very easy to use and you can get colors in various formats instatly.

Inspecting a page html or css files will take too much time.

Here is the link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/color%20picker?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

[Colorzilla](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorzilla/bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp) chrome extension is my favorite and quick.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome released the [EyeDropper API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EyeDropper_API) to a stable release. You can now pick colors directly from your website instead of opening the dev tools.

[image: Preview of color picker]

One tool which can do this is https://pickcoloronline.com/tutorials/pick-color-from-website/

Currently you can only use this in Edge, Chrome and Opera. Other browser support will come probably in the future: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_eyedropper